# Replace only the last matching word in a string

Tags: python, indexing, replace, slice

I want the result to have the result say `"Instead of ice I want pizza"`. I can only figure out how to replace all occurrences of `"ice"` instead of just replacing the last one. I am trying to do this by indexing and slicing but I cannot figure it out, an explanation would be much appreciated.

```py
def replace_last_word(sentence, old, new):
    if sentence.endswith(old):
        i = sentence.index(old)
        new_sentence = (sentence[:i] + new)
        return new_sentence
    return sentence

print(replace_last_word("Instead of ice I want ice", "ice", "pizza"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use negative step slicing to reverse strings, then take advantage of the [`count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) argument of the string `.replace()` method:

```
def replace_last_word(sentence, old, new):
    return sentence[::-1].replace(old[::-1], new[::-1], 1)[::-1]
```

Your program should then print:

```
'Instead of ice i want pizza'
```

It will also work if the sentence does not end with the keyword:

```
print(replace_last_word("Instead of ice i want ice and coke", "ice", "pizza"))
```

```
Instead of ice i want pizza and coke
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `rindex` (instead of `index`) to search from the end.

```py
i = sentence.rindex(old)
```

If the string to be replaced is not always at the end, you will have to append the leftover slice.

```py
def replace_last_word(sentence, old, new):
    i = sentence.rfind(old)
    if i != -1:
        sentence = sentence[:i] + new + sentence[i+len(old):]
    return sentence
```

Comment: Then what? What if `ice` is not the last word of the sentence?

Comment: @Selcuk Considering the fact that the code in the question already checks `if sentence.endswith(old)`, that does not appear to be a concern.

Comment: Fair point, but obviously the code in the question does not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

By converting **sentence** into a **list of words** checking whether the **old word** present in the list of words **iterating from end to start** if it present just change that word and break the loop.. or if not just print the same sentence

**Code:-**

```
def replace_last_word(sentence, old, new):
    sentence=sentence.split()
    for i in range(len(sentence)-1,-1,-1):
        if sentence[i]==old:
            sentence[i]=new
            break
    return " ".join(sentence)

print(replace_last_word("Instead of ice i want ice", "ice", "pizza"))
```